# Android Studio showing Duplicate class found

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic3, capacitor

When generating release build android studio throwing below errors. Which i am not able to resolve. I tried many way which related issue mentioned but didn't succeed.

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhx found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzmz found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzna found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznb found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznc found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznd found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzga found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:19.0.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhe found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhf found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhg found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhh found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhi found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhj found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzio found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzit found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-20.1.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:20.1.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
```

I also added `android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true` inside gradle.properties file.

**My build.gradle file looks like below**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


  namespace 'com.pp.prescriptionpatriot'
  compileSdkVersion 32
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pp.prescriptionpatriot"
    minSdkVersion 29
    targetSdkVersion 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

repositories {
  flatDir{
    dirs '../capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/src/main/libs', 'libs'
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

  // Branch: required for all Android apps
  implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:5.2.3'

  // Branch: required if your app is in the Google Play Store (tip: avoid using bundled play services libs)
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:20.0.0' // App indexing
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0' // GAID matching

  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
  implementation project(':capacitor-android')
  testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
  androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
  androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
  implementation project(':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins')
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
  //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.1.0'
  //implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'



}

apply from: 'capacitor.build.gradle'

try {
  def servicesJSON = file('google-services.json')
  if (servicesJSON.text) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  logger.warn("google-services.json not found, google-services plugin not applied. Push Notifications won't work")
}
```

Comment: try with implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'

Comment: @VineshChauhan i am using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0` but again getting `Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbo found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.4.2-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.4.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-18.0.3-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:18.0.3)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this replacing below implementation as per @VineshChauhan comment.

**From**

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0'`

**To**

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'`

Answer (score 3):

In your **gradle.properties** file, Add below line then rebuild your project.

> `android.enableJetifier=true`

---

Comment: iIt's already there in gradle.properties file.  `android.useAndroidX=true`
`android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: share your build.gradle (App) file for better checking the issue