# Ionic android release build apk has below issue

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-manifest, capacitor, release-apk

I have below issue

**Type com.amc.patientapp.BuildConfig is defined multiple times**

I have two
build.gradle file in my ionic angular project when I open it in Android studio

1. inside **app** folder - **build.gradle**
2. inside **capacitor-Cordova-android-plugins** folder - **build.gradle**

both the build.gradle gradle file has same namespace **com.amc.patientapp** , it will create **debug** apk successfully but while creating **release** apk , I got this issue - Type **com.amc.patientapp.BuildConfig is defined multiple times**
not sure what is going wrong here.

Please help me to resolved this issue .
I am using ionic project with capacitor and android studio to create build apk .
Normal build apk has no issue it has created successfully, but issue in release apk only .
I am going to create release apk with new JSK information as old JKS has lost.
I will ask play store team to update new JKS into same app id , so I can update the app.Your guidance are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is exactly your issue, question here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Kaddath please see my updated issue .

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge, never used capacitor and IIRC didn't use Android Studio to sign release apps, built them with ionic and signed in command line. I gave you an upvote so you're not in negative anymore, good luck for the answer, usually the boring questions are answered quick, but interesting ones can take time. I found this just in case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912275/android-studio-showing-duplicate-class-found you may need to add additional info like capacitor and android studio versions and bundle file, it can help from what I read